# Extract a specific row from a combination matrix

Tags: matlab, combinatorics

Suppose I have 121 elements and want to get all combinations of 4 elements taken at a time, i.e. 121c4.
Since `combnk(1:121, 4)` takes a lot of time, I want to go for 2% of that combination by providing:

```
z = 1:50:length(121c4(:, 1))
```

For example: 1<sup>st</sup> row, 5<sup>th</sup> row, 100<sup>th</sup> row and so on, up to 121c4, picking only those rows from a 121c4 matrix without generating the complete combination (it's consuming too much for large numbers like 625c4).

Comment: Do the rows have to be exactly evenly spaced, why not just generate your own data?

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't defined an ordering on the combinations, why not just use

```
randi(121,p,4)
```

where `p` is the number of combinations you want in your set ?  With this approach you may, or may not, want to replace duplicates.

If you have defined an ordering on the combinations, tell us what it is.